Calculating similarities and associated p values between count vectors with weights
I am trying to choose the best approach to calculate pairwise similarity and
significance.
I have multiple groups, each with counts in several categories. For
illustration purposes, groups may be documents, and categories may be words.
x <- c(1, 10, 3, 0, 0, 6)
y <- c(1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 0)

I am interested in the similarity between groups.  Groups x and y may have
originated from the same process, or they may be independent. If they are more
similar, it is more likely that they have a common origin.
Currently, I am using cosine similarity for this purpose. Because not all
categories (or words) carry the same amount of information, I apply weights.
Rarer words should be more impactful in calculating similarity than more
frequent words. To stay in the language world, inverse document frequency is
often used for this, which is based on the relative occurrence frequency of
words.
I have considered other similarity measures, such as the Kullback-Leibler
Divergence and the Jensen-Shannon Divergence. I do not currently favor them
because they cannot include weights. However, maybe these metrics are more
suitable than the cosine with approach "Multinomial resampling, considering
category frequencies" (see below)?
Note that these probabilities do not sum to one because not all possible
categories/words are included in the count vector.
# Sampling probabilities of categories/words
probs <- c(1e-10, 1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-2, 1e-2, 1e-1)
# Inverse document frequencies as weights
weights <- -log10(probs)

cosine_sim <- function(x, y, weights) {
    x <- x * weights
    y <- y * weights
    sum(x * y) / (sqrt(sum(x^2)) * sqrt(sum(y^2)))
}
res <- cosine_sim(x, y, weights)
# 0.8137255

Is the resultant cosine similarity statistically significant?
To calculate this, I can think of at least three approaches, and I wonder which
one would be best suited:
Permutation
Permute the count vectors of both groups, then calculate cosine similarities.
Note that weights are applied after permutation of the raw counts.
res_permuted <- replicate(1000, {
    cosine_sim(sample(x), sample(y), weights)
})
p_permuted <- (sum(res_permuted >= res) + 1) / (length(res_permuted) + 1)

Multinomial resampling, ignoring category frequencies
Evenly redistribute the counts between all possibilities.
res_multinom <- replicate(1000, {
    n_x <- sum(x)
    n_y <- sum(y)
    sample_x <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = n_x, prob = rep(1 / length(x), length(x)))
    sample_y <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = n_y, prob = rep(1 / length(y), length(y)))
    cosine_sim(sample_x, sample_y, weights)
})
p_multinom <- (sum(res_multinom >= res) + 1) / (length(res_multinom) + 1)

Multinomial resampling, considering category frequencies
This incorporates the sampling frequencies of categories/words in two places.
Is this fair to do?
res_multinom2 <- replicate(1000, {
    n_x <- sum(x)
    n_y <- sum(y)
    sample_x <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = n_x, prob = probs)
    sample_y <- rmultinom(n = 1, size = n_y, prob = probs)
    cosine_sim(sample_x, sample_y, weights)
})
p_multinom2 <- (sum(res_multinom2 >= res) + 1) / (length(res_multinom2) + 1)

